# marklogic data copy from one forest to multiple forest

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I need to copy the Marklogic DB contents (50 million xml docs) from one DB host to another. We can do this by doing a backup/restore. But i need to copy the data available in two forests (25 million each) to 20 forests (2.5 million each) and distribute them evenly. can this be done using xqsync or any other utilities?

Comment: I think XQSync will automatically distribute among all available target forests, unless otherwise specified. This could be verified with a small scale test.

Comment: Also, see https://github.com/mblakele/corb-rebalancer for rebalancing newly added forests. And note that forest rebalancing is built into MarkLogic 7.

Comment: For ML6 and earlier, I favor https://github.com/mblakele/task-rebalancer over corb-rebalancer. It might a little more trouble to set up, but much more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wst indicates, Marklogic 7 will do that automatically for you by default for new databases. For databases that you upgrade from earlier versions, you need to enable rebalancing manualy from Admin interface. You can find that setting on the Database Configure tab, near the bottom.

After that, you just add new forests as needed to your database, and redistribution is automatically triggered after a slight delay (based on a throttle-level like reindexer), also accross a cluster. You can follow rebalancing from the Database Status page in the Admin interface. May take a while though, it is designed to run with low interference on background.

The other way around is almost as easy. Go to Forests page under Database, and select 'retired' next to the forest you want to remove. This automatically triggers rebalancing documents away from that forest. Once that is done, you just detach it from the Database.

All data is fully searchable and accessible during all this, though response times can be relatively slow, as caches need to be refreshed as well.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the process of doing the same migration this week. 14M documents from two forests on a single host to a cluster and six forests. We have done a couple trial runs of the migration and use backup/restore followed by a forest rename then adding the new forests to the cluster. We then use CORB to do the re-balance. A little fine tuning to optimize the number of threads and we had to adjust a linux TCP timeout to make sure the CORB process didn't fail part way through the re-balance. I think we ended up using CORB based on the very old version of ML we are currently running.

If you are lucky to be able to run under ML7 then this is all a lot easier along with much reduced forest storage needs.

Answer (score 0):

With ML6 or earlier I would use back and restore to move the forests, then https://github.com/mblakele/task-rebalancer to rebalance. Afterwards you'll probably want to force a merge, to get rid of the deleted fragments in the original forests.